# What does these hex values mean?

Tags: hex, hexdump, hex-editors

I have a table of values of hex values (I think they are hex bytes?) and I'm trying to figure out what they mean in decimal.

[image]

On the website the author states that the highlighted values **43 7A 00 00** mean **250** in decimal, but when I input these into a hex to decimal converter I get **1132068864**.

For the life of me I don't understand what's going on. I know that the naming above the highlighted values *1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 A B C D E F* are the hex system, but I don't understand how you read the values inside the table.

Help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's happening here is that the bytes **43 7A 00 00** are not being treated as an integer.  They are being treated as an IEEE-format 32-bit floating-point number.  This is why the `Type` column in the `Inspector` window in the image says `Float`.  When those bytes are interpreted in that way they do indeed represent the value 250.0.

You can read about the details of the format at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format

In this particular case the bytes would be decoded as:

- a "sign" bit of `0`, meaning that the value is a positive number
- an "exponent" field containing bits `1000 0110` (or hex **86**, decimal 134), meaning that the exponent has the value 7 (calculated by subtracting 127 from the raw value of the field, 134)
- a "significand" field containing bits `1111 1010 0000 0000 0000 0000` (or hex **FA0000**, decimal 16384000)

The significand and exponent are combined according to the formula:

```
    value = ( significand * (2 ^ exponent) ) / (2 ^ 23)
```

where **a ^ b** means "**a** raised to the power **b**" .

In this case that gives:

```
    value = ( 16384000 * 2^7 ) / 2^23
          = ( 16384000 * 128 ) / 8388608
          = 250.0
```